# Rebuild EXE after DLL updated?

Tags: c, windows, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I saw topics and microsoft official doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/determining-which-exporting-method-to-use), said that after we add an exporting function to our dll, we have to rebuild the DLL (logic) **AND** the EXE.
I don't understand why they say that, after tests it is not the case, i don't have to rebuild my exe after i add functions to my dll.

My functions are exported with __declspec and there are basic C functions. 
They (the link) advice us to use .def file with ordinal numbers to don't have to rebuild, but even without this .def file, i don't have to rebuild.

Does __declspec also use ordinal numbers to link dll functions or does it use function naming ? Could you explain me why they say that, where am i wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: In the docs: "If you rebuild the DLL with new exports, you also have to rebuild the applications because the decorated names for exported C++ functions might change if you use a different version of the compiler to rebuild it."

Comment: @tadman That reads like an answer, wouldn't you want to make one?

Comment: @Yunnosch It only applies to C++ (name mangling), not C, so I'm just putting that there as a partial answer.

Comment: Yes i have badly read, so if i always compile with the same compiler or if i always use a C compiler i will not have problem ?

Comment: @tadman I see. Partial answers are also adequate participation in the answering process, but that is of course your decision. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @tadman That's just "if you use a different version of the compiler" though.